# "elegant" erlang solution to finding a linux users UID

Tags: erlang

I'm looking for any alternate way to find the UID for a Linux user in erlang (Erlang/OTP 17).

I currently do a call to the shell and use 'id -u $USER' to determine it.

Thanks.

Comment: Far from certain, but Erlang being OS-agnostic, I doubt it has facilities to "elegantly" find something like a Linux UID. Rather, the solution you have is probably as elegant as it gets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no such function in erlang OTP lib.
But you can refer some open source lib:
[https://github.com/gebi/jungerl/blob/master/lib/posix_drv/README](https://github.com/sergey-miryanov/erlang-pwd)

https://github.com/sergey-miryanov/erlang-pwd